# Remove a div after an element in a iframe inside that div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, cookies

I have an AdSense in a div and want to protect it from invalid traffic.
After someone clicked in the ads, it should be hidden and not to be shown after a period of time.

**HTML:**

`<div id="codeWrapper">
        <div id="firstCode">Adsense code here</div>
  </div>`

**CSS:**

```
#codeWrapper { position: relative;}
#firstCode { position: absolute; width: 336px; height: 280px; z-index: 999;}
```

**JS:**

```
$("#firstCode").click(function () {
        var date = new Date();
        var h = "24";
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (h * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        Cookies.set('clicked', 'true', {expires: date, path: '/'});

        $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

I have used javascript cookie to store a date when an ad is clicked and to set the expiry time.

There are no errors in the console but somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: If you `console.log($(this).parent());` what did you get? `codeWrapper`?

Comment: When ads open in a new tab, it doesn't log anything. the same when the ads start redirecting to another url.

Comment: If I remove iframe and click, this is what I get:

`[div#codeWrapper, selector: "", prevObject: a.fn.init[1], context: div#firstCode]`

Answer (score 0):

Actual browsers doesn't allow scripts manipulate the iframe inner content if the iframe has a different server. So, you need check if the iframe url has the same server of your current url.

Comment: OP do not want to do anything with the content of iFrame, he want to remove the parent element of `firstCode` what is `codeWrapper`. Anyway, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: His function returns ```Uncaught ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined``` but works well when remove the cookie's function. Perhaps he needs to debug this object.

https://jsfiddle.net/alexndreazevedo/s9u25yfm/

Comment: Cookies is not defined because you have not implement resource: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: If you use text it works, but it doesn't work when it is ads in iframe

Comment: Actually, you need to verify if ads iframe is on the same server url of your page. Due to restrictions of browsers, isn't possible to manipulate inner content of iframes from another server. Please, check it and we can try another solution.

Comment: Better approach! Nice job.